# flot chart in angular.js directive has zero dimensions

Tags: angularjs, flot, angularjs-directive

I have followed the sample code that embeds a flot chart inside a angular.js directive: https://gist.github.com/jrmoran/3966529

The problem is that the outer `chart` element ends up being of zero width and height. Here is my test code: http://jsfiddle.net/pVEDL/. Because of this I am having problems with layout.

In addition, unless I hide the container element before calling `$.plot` on it, flot throws an exception saying that the chart has zero dimensions. Why do I have to hide the container element?

Comment: While not exactly a duplicate, the problem you're having is the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14855643/angularjs-directive-reports-wrong-height where a simple solution is given: give your custom AngularJS directive a "display: block" style.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ended up having

```
template: '<div></div>',
replace: true,
```

in my directive definition, which helped.

Answer (score 2):

This one caused me a lot of headache. Solution is to make directive bind to 'A' (attribute) instead of 'E' (element). There seems to be something related to the creation of the custom element in angular messing with the size/style.

So, change restrict to 'A' in the directive and change the `<chart>` to `<div chart="">` and everything should be working.

HTML:

```
<div ng-app='App'>
    <div ng-controller='Ctrl'>
        <div class="chart" chart="" ng-model='data'>        
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Directive:

```
App.directive('chart', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            var data = scope[attrs.ngModel];
            $.plot(elem, data, {});
        }
    };
});
```

Please be aware that even though the code in the gist seems to work, the layout is severely broken. The text (look in the fiddle) is misplaced. If using the text to canvas plugin you won't see anything for instance. This should fix it as shown in this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/TDwGF/219/

Comment: thanks. I had to add a template to my directive, and now it works.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/TDwGF/219/ is not working. can you please suggest the right solution?